# How to create a query to display the total sales per Date for this week sql

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions

This is the tables and their respective column name

Product (prodid, prodname, supplierid, price)
Customer(custid,custname)
supplier(supplierid,suppliername)
sales(salesid, custid, date)
salesdet (id, salesid, prodid, qty)

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregate function and `date_trunc` as follows:

```
Select date_trunc('day', s.date) as date_,
       Sum(sd.qty*p.price) as total_sales
  From sales s 
  Join salesdet sd on s.salesid = sd.salesid
  Join product p on p.prodid = sd.prodid
 Where date_trunc('week', s.date) = date_trunc('week', current_timestamp)
  Group by date_trunc('day', s.date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to join the tables wherever required based on foreign keys and add a group by clause for grouping the result based on the date. Try to map out the tables to understand the number of joins required. The query would be something like this:

```
Select date, product.price * qty
From sales
Join salesdet on salesdet.salesid = sales.salesid
Join product on product.prodid = salesdet.prodid
Group by date,  product.price * qty
```